# The self.__dict__ dict in parent does not have child attributes?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have two classes:

```
class Base(object):
  def __init__(self):
    object.__init__(self)

  def print_methods(self):
    print self.__dict__

class Child(Base):
   def __init__(self):
     Base.__init__(self)

   def another_method(self):
     pass
```

Now I can to call the `print_method` in a `Child` instance, and expecting to see the  `another_method`. But failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not related to inheritance at all.  `Child.another_method()` is an attribute of the class, not the instance, so it's not in the `__dict__` of `self`, but rather in the dict of `Child`.  If you create an instance of `Base` only and call `print_methods()` on this instance, you won't see `print_methods` as well.

To find all methods of an instance, you can use `dir()` or `inspect.getmembers()` (possible in combination with `callable()` to only include the callable attributes).